# Including file as well as other information with HttpClient postAsync call

Tags: c#

I'm trying to duplicate a call that i've done with postman (see screenshot) [image: postman]

The problem I'm currently having is that I need to include text data as well as a file. Thankfully, I've found the MultipartFormDataContent, but I seem to be running into problems with the content I'm passing.

```
var content = new MultiPartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent("test file name"), "name");
content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes), "file);
client.postAsync(url, content);
```

Comment: 404 error when making the call. It seems to be that the api is expecting the content in a different format.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you John, I will keep that in mind for future posts

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569770/wrong-content-type-header-generated-using-multipartformdatacontent). If this doesn't help, you might want to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check what your program is sending and compare it to what PostMan sends.