# Xamarin.Android: HttpClient with MultipartFormDataContent returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, httpclient, multipartform-data, bad-request

I develop a **Xamarin.Android app** and I need to update an audio recorded file.

For this, my client has provided me an API like this:

- URL: /api/recordings/
- Method: POST
- Data format: multipart/form-data
- Fields: some text fields and the audio file to send

When I test it on **Postman**, it **works fine**. The generate code snippets are:

```
POST /api/recordings/ HTTP/1.1
Host: X.X.X.X
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1" 
param1 name

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param2"
param2 name

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio_file"; filename="xxx.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav
```

But when I try **from the app**, I get an **400 - Bad Request error**.

**First attempt:**

I first tried with the following basic code:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{       
    try
    {
        MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        formData.Add(new StringContent("param1 name"), "param1");
        formData.Add(new StringContent("param2 name"), "param2");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, formData);
        Logger.Log("Response : " + responseObj.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Log("Exception : " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

But there is a **400 - Bad Request error**:

```
Response : StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Server: nginx/1.15.0
  Date: Mon, 25 Jun 2018 23:25:41 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Cookie
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 85
  Allow: POST, OPTIONS
}
```

**Second attempt:**

Then I've tried the following snippet that I found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569770/wrong-content-type-header-generated-using-multipartformdatacontent):

```
string servResp = "";
string boundary = "----CustomBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary))
{
    content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    content.Add(new StringContent("param1 name"), "param1");
    content.Add(new StringContent("param2 name"), "param2");

    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    handler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    request.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
    request.Content = content;
    try
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        servResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Log("PostTest() - Exception : " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
return servResp;
```

But there is still a **400 - Bad Request error**:

```
Exception : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 400 (Bad Request)
  at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode () [0x0002a] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0
```

***=> Would you have any explanation? How could I fix this?***

**Edit : the audio file**

I haven't specified the code of the audio file, I use a ByteArrayContent in both cases:

```
byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullFilePath);
formData.Add(new ByteArrayContent(b, 0, b.Length), "audio_file", "audio.wav");
```

**Conclusion:**

I was able to resolve my problem by creating a console project that using the same service: this allows me to find and fix my error.

For an other issue, I followed the Fiddler [instructions](http://Do%20you%20know%20an%20alternative%20%20to%20Fiddler%20that%20could%20work%20on%20Android%20devices?) to parameter proxy on the device. However, it seems that the proxy doesn't work for apps but only for websites in the latest versions of Android...

***Do you know an alternative  to Fiddler that could work on Android devices?***

Comment: Every webpage is different so what works on one webpage may not work on another.  Since it works with Postman I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the results.  Then compare the headers in Postman with your app and find the differences.  Normally just adding a missing header in your request will solve issue.

Comment: @mjwills I've added the code of the audio file upload, it was an oversight on my part, but I still have the same problem with the ByteArrayContent.

Comment: @jdweng I don't see how to use Fiddler on an Android device for a Xamarin app. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The transport layer for your request/response is TCP which is a connection.  You can monitor the traffic one any computer containing the connection (Client, Server, intermediate Router) or use a Proxy Server.  See following : http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid

Comment: You can proxy your phone from the pc, in case of https traffic you should install a certificate.

Comment: I finally create a basic console project that allowing me to get the logs in Fiddler. This allowed me to fix my issue: it was only a parameter that was badly written...

Comment: Finally I encountered an error on my Android device and I followed the Fiddler instructions. However, it seems that the proxy doesn't work for apps but only for websites in the latest versions of Android...